# How to determine whether a argument is string or number in a shell script?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am a beginner in bash scripting. I tried to create a script to determine if a number is odd or even. The program is supposed to exit when it is given a string or more than 1 argument. It is working fine in every case but it can't detect an even number. It is behaving like it is passed a string!
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM=$1
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Please pass a number to determine whether it's odd or even!"
        exit 1
fi
let RESULT=NUM%2
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Please enter an integer! Exit Status: 2."
        exit 2
fi
if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "This is an even number!"
else
        echo "this is an odd number"
fi
```

**output:**
[image]

Comment: `let` will exit with nonzero status if its calculated result is 0.

Comment: Please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 2):

Doing arithmetic in the shell is a bit awkward. It's possible, but I like to try to avoid it.

In your special case, checking if a number is even or odd, observe that the last digit of an even number is one of 0, 2, 4, 6, 8. What about matching against a glob pattern?

```
case $1 in
  (*[!0123456789]*)
    echo "$1 does not look like a number";;
  (*[02468])
    echo "$1 is even";;
  (*)
    echo "$1 is odd";;
esac
```

The proper way to do arithmetic in the POSIX shell is with *arithmetic expansion*, using `$(( ))`:

```
NUM=42
x=$((NUM % 2))   # assigns x=0
if [ "$x" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo even
fi
```

If you need to compute integer numbers beyond 32 or 64 bits, you can use the bc(1) utility, which is an arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic language and calculator:

```
$ echo '1234567890 * 9876543210' | bc
12193263111263526900
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the return code of `let`.
(*Gordon Davisson* already stated this in his comment above)

Read at `man bash`:

```
let arg [arg ...]
  ... If the last arg evaluates to 0, let returns 1; 0 is returned otherwise.
```

Your test `[ $? -ne 0 ]` of the `let` return code will also filter the even values.

So the easiest way to fix your code is to avoid `let` and use the common way to do arithmetics in shell scripts: `result=$(( num % 2 ))`

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$1
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Please pass a number to determine whether it's odd or even!"
    exit 1
fi
if ! ([ $num -ge 0 ] || [ $num -lt 0 ]); then
    echo "Please pass an integer but not a string for evaluation."
    exit 1
fi 2>/dev/null

result=$(( num % 2 ))
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Please enter an integer! Exit Status: 2."
    exit 2
fi
if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "This is an even number!"
else
    echo "this is an odd number"
fi
```

EDIT: Not part of the question but necessary is a proper recognition for the parameter being an integer value.
So I added the test `([ $num -ge 0 ] || [ $num -lt 0 ])` that will turn TRUE on all integers but generates an error on strings, as the syntax `-lt` is only valid for integers, but for strings the syntax `<` is expected.

Comment: I tried with $(( )) but it exits with 0 even when the NUM variable is a string!

Comment: Well, the question was to get the odd/even evaluation to work. The string has not been part of the question. — I extended the code by a test, that will fail when `$NUM` is a string. (Reason for test failure: One must not use the syntax `-lt`  for strings but `<`)

Comment: Did the code extension solve your problem?